# ¿Por que un RecyclerView me deja una vista con residuos?

Tags: android, recyclerview, viewmodel

he trabajado con el recyclerviews y esta la primera vez que me pasas les comparto una pantalla
la imagen esta recortada por motivos de seguridad  pero ahi se muestra el problema que tiene esto pasa cuando lo roto  y se vuleve a cargar la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les dejo mi codigo del fragment que usa

```
public class RTNotebookFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
private int mColumnCount = 1;
private List<RTNotebook> rtNotebookList;
private RTNotebookRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private RTNotebookViewModel rtNotebookViewModel;

public RTNotebookFragment() {  }

public static RTNotebookFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    RTNotebookFragment fragment = new RTNotebookFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();

        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }

        rtNotebookList = new ArrayList<>();
        rtNotebookList.clear();

        adapter = new RTNotebookRecyclerViewAdapter(rtNotebookList, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        lanzarViewModel();
    }
    return view;
}

private void lanzarViewModel() {
    rtNotebookViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(RTNotebookViewModel.class);
    rtNotebookViewModel.getLVL().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<RTNotebook>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<RTNotebook> rtNotebooks) {
            adapter.setNuevosRTNotebook(rtNotebooks);
        }
    });
}
}
```

La actividad que utiliza practiacmente todo lo hace el fragment:

```
public class RTNotebookActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConectaFragments {


Context ctx;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.r_t_notebook_activity);

    
    ctx = this;

   
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contenedor, new RTNotebookFragment())
            .commit();



}
```

el adapter para el recyclerview

```
public class RTNotebookRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RTNotebookRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<RTNotebook> mValues;
private Context context;

public RTNotebookRecyclerViewAdapter(List<RTNotebook> items, Context ctx) {
    mValues = items;
    this.context = ctx;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.item1.setText(holder.mItem.getId_tipomov_position());
    holder.item2.setText(holder.mItem.getReferencia_BRIC());
    holder.item3.setText(holder.mItem.getReferencia_ECC());
    holder.item4.setText(holder.mItem.getReferencia_Otra());
    holder.item21.setText(holder.mItem.getRendimiento());
    holder.item22.setText(holder.mItem.getMancha());
    holder.item23.setText(holder.mItem.getImperfecciones());
    holder.item24.setText(holder.mItem.getKilos_cafe());
    holder.item31.setText(cambiafecha2(holder.mItem.getMes()));
    holder.item32.setText(holder.mItem.getHedge());
    holder.item33.setText(holder.mItem.getHedgeyear());
    holder.item34.setText(holder.mItem.getPos());
    holder.item41.setText(holder.mItem.getTercero());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public void setNuevosRTNotebook(List<RTNotebook> rtNotebooks) {
    this.mValues = rtNotebooks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private String cambiafecha2(String cadenafecha) {
    String fecha = null;
    SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yyyy");

    try {
        if (cadenafecha == null) {
            fecha = "9999-12-31T00:00:00";
        } else {
            Date date = p.parse(cadenafecha);
            fecha = f.format(date);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fecha;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final EditText item1;
    public final EditText item2;
    public final EditText item3;
    public final EditText item4;
    public final EditText item21;
    public final EditText item22;
    public final EditText item23;
    public final EditText item24;
    public final EditText item31;
    public final EditText item32;
    public final EditText item33;
    public final EditText item34;
    public final EditText item41;
   // public final EditText item14;

    public RTNotebook mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        item1 = view.findViewById(R.id.item11);
        item2 = view.findViewById(R.id.item12);
        item3 = view.findViewById(R.id.item13);
        item4 = view.findViewById(R.id.item14);
        item21 = view.findViewById(R.id.item21);
        item22 = view.findViewById(R.id.item22);
        item23 = view.findViewById(R.id.item23);
        item24 = view.findViewById(R.id.item24);
        item31 = view.findViewById(R.id.item31);
        item32 = view.findViewById(R.id.item32);
        item33 = view.findViewById(R.id.item33);
        item34 = view.findViewById(R.id.item34);
        item41 = view.findViewById(R.id.item41);
        //item14 = view.findViewById(R.id.item44);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + item1.getText() + "'";
    }
}
}
```

el codigo del viewmodel

```
public class RTNotebookViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private LiveData<List<RTNotebook>> allList;
private RTNotebookRepository repository_;

public RTNotebookViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository_ = new RTNotebookRepository(application);
    allList = repository_.getAll();
}

public LiveData<List<RTNotebook>> getLVL(){
    return allList;
}

public void insert(RTNotebook rtNotebook){
    repository_.insertar(rtNotebook);
}

public void deleteAll(){
    repository_.deleteAll();
}

public void deleteAllStatus(){
    repository_.deleteAllByStatus();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimino los fragments previamente cargados al iniciar la actividad, si lo hay claro esta.

```
 for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }


    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contenedor, new RTNotebookFragment())
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que los datos duplicados se agregan porque el viewmodel mantiene el estado cuando rotas la pantalla, mientras que el fragment se destruye, prueba agregando una validacion a tu viewModel

```
public RTNotebookViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository_ = new RTNotebookRepository(application);
   if(allList != null){
      return
   }
 allList = repository_.getAll();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el tiempo... lo puede resolver, el detalle estaba que al rotar se vuelve a cargar el fragment, asi que elimino los o fragments cargados al getSupportFragmentManager()                                                                                             
     for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
          }